# Related Lists Not Pulling The Object - how do I solve this?

Tags: leads, related-list

In my org, Leads have 1 Account. I have a process running daily to link the 2 objects.

This is reflect properly on the Lead Page via Account Field, but not with my Account Related List the same page.  My related lists of "Accounts" shows 0, but I literally see the account lower in the page.  Here is Screenshot of a lead record

[image]
[image]

This makes no sense to me.  Can anyone point me in the right direction to solve this?

Thank you!

Comment: It looks like your Lead object has an Account field, but also your Account object has a Lead field. This latter relationship is what is shown on the related list. The Account on the Lead page that you see on your screenshot will only appear in the related list on the Account record page.

Comment: Thank you @GuyClairbois I follow you, but remain confused on what to do because my Account page is showing the correct Lead Related List count (and Lead). - I added a 2nd screenshot above

Comment: Lookup relationships are one-to-many. So on one end you will see only 1 field with in this case an Account. On the Account end you might see multiple Leads in the related list, because multiple Leads could have the same Account on the lookup field. 
The lookup relationship that is the other way around is completely independent from this, and is not related to the first one.
So in order to help you further, we'd need to know what business functionality you are trying to achieve.